# I have an error when deploying bios contract

Tags: nodeos, testnet, permissions, single-node

Please help me to solve a problem.

I recently updated eosio to v1.0.5 and got an error while deploying bios contract. I had no such problems neither with version v1.0.2 nor with v1.0.1.
I followed the "getting started" manual and got stuck on the line below:

`cleos set contract eosio build/contracts/eosio.bios -p eosio.`

with error:

`Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.`

I don't know if it could help you, but I also struggled with creating a wallet:
`cleos wallet create`
but solved it (thanks to #3879) by explicitly passing the port number to keosd:

`keosd --http-server-address localhost:8900`

I have also tried to explicitly provide url to cleos:

`cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8900 set contract eosio ${EOSIO_SOURCE}/build/contracts/eosio.bios -p eosio`

But I got the same error:

`Reading WAST/WASM from /home/src/eos//build/contracts/eosio.bios/eosio.bios.wasm...
Using already assembled WASM...
Publishing contract...
Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.`

So I use `localhost:8900` for launching keosd and `http://localhost:8900` for cleos.
Note, that I have imported the private key and unlocked the wallet.: 

 `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8900 wallet list keys
Wallets:
[
  "default *"
]
[
  "EOS68qW7HnQYhMtvy58Jx2jdeoHyc8quymYU7tA4xLWQAgpiQM4vW"
]`

Please, tell me what should I do? Or how can I provide more of useful information to help solving the problem?

A little more additional information: nodeos is launched with the following command:
`nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --replay-blockchain --contracts-console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in keypair of eosio is set as follows. You can also solve this problem by importing this key.

5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV

This keypair is created automatically when you create a wallet.
I do not use v1.0.5, so I do not know if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently solved it by myself, but it still may help someone:

First, open `config.ini` - the configuration file of the nodeos, you may find it here: `/root/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config`.
Here you will find something like this:
`signature-provider = EOS${PUBLIC_KEY}=KEY:${PRIVATE_KEY}`
Copy the ${PRIVATE_KEY} into a clipboard.
Now, unlock your wallet:
`cleos wallet unlock` (you will have to enter a password you have got after creating a default wallet)
And, finally, import the ${PRIVATE_KEY} into your wallet:
`cleos wallet import ${PRIVATE_KEY}`
Now you can sign transactions with eosio permissions!

Comment: I tried to [Ivan's answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1051/1815) but it's failed with error : **Assert Exception(10)**. Also the reason the posting an answer is the reputation limit.